# When can i use having count or just Greater than or Less than

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm just curios why i can't use greater than in the following exercise

**Write a query in SQL to display the full name (first and last name) of manager who is supervising 4 or more employees**

The right code for my sub-query is the following ( by using having count )

```
SELECT e.first_name , e.last_name ,e.department_id
FROM employees e
WHERE e.employee_id IN
(SELECT e.manager_id
FROM employees e
GROUP BY e.manager_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>=4);
```

This code returns 15 rows

And the wrong code with greater than

```
SELECT e.first_name , e.last_name ,e.department_id
FROM employees e
WHERE e.employee_id IN
(SELECT e.manager_id
FROM employees e where e.manager_id>=4);
```

This code returns 18 rows

Comment: what s your question

Comment: since subqueries are different.

Comment: `e.manager_id>=4`. PEBCAK. You're not counting anything, you're just checking if manager id is greater than 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query to get the desired output is incorrect.
In where clause you are checking the manager id >=4 or not instead of count.

For your OP this is one of my solution to get a clear understanding

```
SELECT E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME,E.DEPARTMENT_ID
FROM EMPLOYEES E
WHERE E.EMPLOYEE_ID IN( 
SELECT MANAGER_ID FROM 
(
   SELECT M.MANAGER_ID,COUNT(*) CNT FROM EMPLOYEE M
   GROUP BY M.MANAGER_ID 
)
WHERE CNT >= 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The where clause will return all the managers that has manager_id>4.
Whereas the Having clause will return the total count or count greater than 4